# Customizing logged-in Customers name and link in top bar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got this code that allow me to display the logged-in customer in main header menu.

what I want is to change the location (or place) in the header (not in the menu), to change the color and the link url of this displayed username in the menu.

That was the code I was using to display it in the menu:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item');
function my_custom_menu_item($items)
{
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
        $name=$user->display_name; // or user_login , user_firstname, user_lastname
        $items .= '<li><a href="">'.$name.'</a></li>';

    }
    return $items;
}
```

Here is the generated header top bar HTML code where I would like to have this, in the right after the mini-cart:

```html
<div id="top-header">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="et-info"></div>
        <div class="et-secondary-menu">
            <div class="et-duplicate-social-icons"></div>
            <a class="et-cart-info" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible making a function that you will use in your **`header.php`** theme file:

```
function topbar_logged_user( $link = '#' ) {

    // get the currect user
    $cur_user = wp_get_current_user(); // $cur_user->display_name (or user_login , user_firstname, user_lastname)

    // loggin users only
    if ( $cur_user->exists() )
        echo '<a class="user-topbar" href="' . $link . '">' . $cur_user->display_name . '</a>';
}
```

*This code goes on **`function.php`** file of your active child theme (or theme) OR in plugin files too.*

---

**USAGE** in your **`header.php`** active child theme file *(or active theme)*

```
<div id="top-header">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="et-info"></div>
        <div class="et-secondary-menu">
            <div class="et-duplicate-social-icons"></div>
            <a class="et-cart-info" href="#"></a>
            <?php function topbar_logged_user( 'your_link_in_here' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in **`style.css`** CSS file of your active child theme (or theme), you could add something like this for example:

```css
a.user-topbar {
    color: #999;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can add/change custom css rules to fit your needs.

**This should work**